# How to create a logic circuit that takes 3 inputs and returns 1 only when all the inputs are equal?

Tags: math, logic, circuit

I'm struggling with creating a logic circuit that could implement the following truth table:
[image: Truth table for the circuit]

Comment: Why is "AND all inputs and OR the result with an AND of all negated inputs" not the answer?

Comment: But, this is not a programming question, i.e. it is off-topic on StackOverflow  for lacking focus on the programming aspect of the question.

Answer (score 0):

(A'B'C') + (ABC)

You might be interested to check out [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: I wonder why that most obvious answer did not occur to OP. So much so that I assume that the question has some level of complexity not yet specified. Let's see whether OP gives feedback on my clarification question or your assumption-based answer.... Would you like to show an ascii-art version of a corresponding KV diagram?

Comment: I guess it's a little intimidating for people not familiar with Karnaugh map. I can't imagine what else OP would be looking for. Please go ahead if you want to post a more detailed answer